# How to replace a part of a string in python from CSV file?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, csv, webdriver

I used a Selenium and web driver to crawl some information and output a CSV file.

And then, I want to use read CSV file to catch HTML code and remove a part of the string.

I tried to use the replace method to remove it, but it failed.

The following is a html example:

```
<div class="ContentGrid">
    香港一年GDP 都3千幾億大美金
    <br>
    2成都6百幾
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>

<div class="ContentGrid">
    <blockquote>
        <div style="color: #0000A0;">
            <blockquote>
                <div style="color: #0000A0;">
                    藍店送聖誕卡比施生有乜下場
                    <img data-icons="???" src="/faces/wonder2.gif" alt="???">
                </div>
            </blockquote>
            <br>何只聖誕卡，直情要送埋聖誕樹賀一賀佢
            <img data-icons="#hehe#" src="/faces/hehe.gif" alt="#hehe#">
        </div>
    </blockquote>
    <br>
    施生只對聖誕卡有感覺。
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

I have a lot of `div class="ContentGrid"`. However, not every `div class="ContentGrid"` has `<blockquote>...</blockquote>`. So I need to remove all content of `<blockquote>...</blockquote>`

[image]

Below is my expected result:

```
<div class="ContentGrid">
    香港一年GDP 都3千幾億大美金
    <br>
    2成都6百幾
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>

<div class="ContentGrid">

    <br>
    施生只對聖誕卡有感覺。
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
import re

html = """
blah blah blah
    <blockquote>
        blah blah blah
    </blockquote>
blah blah blah
"""

new_html = re.sub("<blockquote>.*</blockquote>", "", html, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(new_html)
```

re.sub replaces the string passed to it in the first parameter with the string passed to it in the second parameter. The third parameter is the string that you want to search through. The .* between the blockquotes means to select any number of unspecified characters except line-breaks. The flags=re.DOTALL will force the . to include line-breaks.

Comment: Great! Sorry, I forgot to mention that you will need to import Python's re module in order to use re.sub . I have edited my post to include the import statement.